# How to fix the "'str' object does not support item assignment" error in MongoDb?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I have a string like this:

```
document = '{ time : 14/09/19 16:00:00,
   global : { full:190 , defects: 7 , btp: 6 , total: 202 } ,
   domains : [ { domain : "A" , full:7 , defects: 2 , btp: 0 , total: 9 },
               { domain : "B" , full:0 , defects: 0 , btp: 0 , total: 0 },
               { domain : "C" , full:6 , defects: 0 , btp: 0 , total: 6 },
               { domain : "D" , full:26 , defects: 0 , btp: 2 , total: 28 },
               { domain : "E" , full:0 , defects: 0 , btp: 0 , total: 0 },
               { domain : "F" , full:4 , defects: 0 , btp: 2 , total: 6 },
               { domain : "G" , full:0 , defects: 0 , btp: 0 , total: 0 },
               { domain : "H" , full:21 , defects: 0 , btp: 1 , total: 22 },
               { domain : "I" , full:32 , defects: 0 , btp: 0 , total: 32 },
               ] }'
```

When I try to insert this into a mongoDB collection, I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

I am clueless about how to convert a string to BSON, in order to execute the insert with it.

I looked in the `bson_util` module, but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the BSON part that matters here. The MongoDB driver will take care of that. Your job is convert JSON to a valid python data structure:

```
import json

data = json.loads(document)

collection.insert(data);
```

Comment: Guess I was overthinking. Thanks!

Comment: @user2215331 I think in general people get "too caught up" in thinking that MongoDB syntax is JSON just because that is what the examples are given in and that is what works with the supplied "shell". JSON is just a way of representing a data structure in a serialized form. The translation  to BSON is much the same except it has a concept of "type"  definitions which is generally required in "strongly typed" languages. As I said, the real point here is use your "native" language methods for describing a data structure when necessary. The job of conversion is up to the driver.

Comment: anyway, to convert to bson: `import bson; bsondoc = bson.BSON.encode(yourdict_or_json)` https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/index.html#bson.BSON

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli Well aware of that. But that was not the question that was asked, even if *"your own search"* somehow led you to this question. The question itself shows ( as answered ) a **misconception** of how to work with a **JSON String**  - *"When I try to insert this into a mongoDB collection"* - and actually was not really asking about BSON at all. Also `yourdict_or_json` is not true. You can **only** convert a `dict` to BSON directly. If you have JSON, then you similarly need to convert just as the answer shows. See `encode` further down the same page you referenced.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the correction. I still think that this question gathers a lot of people asking the actual titled question "How to convert a string to BSON?". So to correct the answer: `import bson, json; bsondoc = bson.BSON.encode(json.loads(your_json_string))`

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli If you actually read the answer *"a lot of people"* really **should not** be attempting to convert to **BSON** at all. The only people ( and a very rare few ) who would possibly need BSON are *driver authors* and *utility authors* for dealing with *data dumps* and the like. Regular *"userland"* applications are simply making the same misconception as the author of the question. Existing MongoDB drivers are meant to take care of the *"native to BSON"* part for you. And **they do!**

Comment: @NeilLunn: some of us are dealing with large amounts of data, in which case being able to convert directly from string to BSON is very helpful. Converting directly from string to BSON means not having to deal with large amounts of python "JSON" objects.

Answer (score 2):

**You rarely have to deal with BSON directly yourself. This is just the format that mongo uses to represent the data internally.**

As a user of the database or one of it's clients, you only need to deal with `key:value` type objects we talk about as documents. In python, `key:value` like objects are most commonly `dict` objects; A dictionary. *You'll need to convert that string into an actual dict-like-object before inserting it into mongo.*

One example of this would be to use the `json` module:

```
>>> import json
>>> document = json.loads('{ time : 14/09/19 16:00:00...')
```

You can now have the `document` object inserted into your collection.