# PyMongo inserting BSON document to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, bson

I would like to insert a new document into my MongoDB collection.

My first input is a string that is shown here:

```
{
    "date" : ISODate("2013-10-06T18:11:26.329Z"),
    "engines" : {},
    "expiration_date" : ISODate("2013-10-06T18:11:36.329Z"),
    "file_name" : "elad.elad",
    "scan_status" : "TEST",
    "task_id" : "4ce4ae9e-ef0a-476a-8189-92a5bfe328bd"
}
```

I'm creating a bson.BSON object with this string:

```
b=bson.BSON(doc)
```

I'm trying to insert it into my collection in MongoDB:

```
collection.insert(b)
```

but I get the following error:
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Does someone know what is the problem here?

Comment: Could you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-convert-a-string-to-bson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898476/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bson). Although `json.loads` would not be able to decode `ISODate` so you would have to create the document with `python  date` object.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you want use BSON for converting data in BSON?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can directly convert string to BSON, you either require `json.loads` or `BSON.encode` method.

You can use following code :

```
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient().test
collection = db.some

doc = {
    "date" : datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-10-06T18:11:26.329Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fz"),
    "engines" : {},
    "expiration_date" : datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-10-06T18:11:36.329Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fz"),
    "file_name" : "elad.elad",
    "scan_status" : "TEST",
    "task_id" : "4ce4ae9e-ef0a-476a-8189-92a5bfe328bd"
}
collection.insert(doc)
```

Here I am using datetime object to convert your string date to Python compatible datetime

Comment: You do not actually use bson here, it would be helpful if you showed how to do that.