# Error on insert_many() : document must be an instance of dict

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I am trying to store json data into a mongoDB using pyMongo and when I run the following python script:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

db = client.twitterdata

f = open('twitterdata.json', 'r')

dblist = []

for line in f:
    dblist.append(line)

db.collection.insert_many(dblist)

f.close()
```

I get the error :

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

The json file, namely `twitterdata.json` has 10 lines each line having a dict. I intend to store the dict at each line as an individual document in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import json

dblist = []
for line in f:
    dblist.append(JSON.loads(line))
```

You are trying to import a list of strings.

Related:

- http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#documents
- https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.4.0/api/bson/json_util.html
- [How to convert a string to BSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898476/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bson)

Comment: It solves the error, can you give a link to documentation or explain how this takes the dict thats inside the string?

Comment: @kartikeykant18 i might be able to expand on how to convert the stringified json into bson, or the `collections.MutableMapping` I didn't look at the documentation to understand what the error was saying. I could see it by looking at the code you gave?